# как обратиться к атрибутам корневого элемента vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

Мне необходимо вытащить значения атрибутов из корневого элемента

```
<div id="app-cart" data-url="http://localhost:3000/products" data-sessid="sessid" data-link-catalog="catalog.html" data-link-index-page="index.html" data-submit-message="Ваша заявка успешно отправлена!<br> В течение 5 минут мы Вам перезвоним" data-params="">
```

пока я обращаюсь через DOM

```
sessid: document.querySelector("#app-cart").getAttribute("data-sessid")
```

Как это сделать правильней?

Comment: по идее, они должны быть в `$root.$attrs`. Но я бы, все-таки, положил их в store и доставал оттуда

Comment: А почему вы передаёте параметры в data-*, а не указывете их в data для приложения vue?

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь свойством экземпляра `$el`, чтобы получить корневой элемент DOM, управляемый этим экземпляром Vue.

После того как элемент получен, получаем его атрибуты: если только [data-* атрибуты](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) необходимо получить, то можно использовать [доступ к data атрибутам в JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes#%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF_%D0%B2_javascript) через [Element.getAttribute()](http://Element.getAttribute()):

```
var attribute = element.getAttribute(attributeName);
```

где `attribute` - переменная, которой будет присвоено значение `attributeName`.
`attributeName` - имя атрибута, значение которого необходимо получить.

или использовать свойство `dataset`, чтобы получить объект `data` свойств:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app-cart',
  data: () => {
    return {
      dataAttr: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.dataAttr = { ...this.$el.dataset
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app-cart" data-url="http://localhost:3000/products" data-sessid="sessid" data-link-catalog="catalog.html" data-link-index-page="index.html" data-submit-message="Ваша заявка успешно отправлена!<br> В течение 5 минут мы Вам перезвоним" data-params="">
  <pre>{{dataAttr}}</pre>
</div>
```